# Why does sep='|' skew results when a comma is present using Pandas to_csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large CSV file which I read into pandas. Some of the data looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'],
              'comment': ['Pasta', 'Pizza', 'Ice Cream, Cake'],
              'cost': [10, 5, 4]})

    name     comment            cost
0   Bob      Pasta              10
1   Jane     Pizza              5
2   Alice    Ice Cream, Cake    4
```

I have been asked to export using pipe (|) as delimiter.

```
df.to_csv('df.csv', sep='|', index=False)
```

However when I open the CSV i notice the comma between Ice Cream and Cake is acting as a separator. There should be no data in Column B.

```
Col A            Col B
name|comment|cost   
Bob|Pasta|10    
Jane|Pizza|5    
Alice|Ice Cream  Cake|4
```

My expected result is:

```
Col A
name|comment|cost
Bob|Pasta|10
Jane|Pizza|5
Alice|Ice Cream, Cake|4
```

Ultimately the data needs to be output as a .txt file but I see the same results when the .txt file is opened in excel and data displayed using 'Text to Columns' function.

I cannot replace the comma with another value. I must maintain the integrity of the data.

Thanks

Comment: I ran your code and got the output you expected.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle that's odd. You see no data in Column B?

Comment: In a raw file as in looking at it as a text file its formated correct, when you open in excel with a csv exention excel will automatically split commas into columns. So this isnt a python or pandas problem. Its an issue with excel

Comment: CSV is a TLA for comma separated vector.  Hence ".csv" extension.  If it's pipe separated it would be far more sensible to use ".psv" extension !